# Angular ngFor not updating DOM when array is updated

Tags: angular

I'm working with Angular and am having an issue with data being displayed to the DOM via `ngFor`.

By default, the `dataArray` variable in my code is empty, but an HTTP post request to a given endpoint updates the array, populating the array with a collection of objects.

I'm able to `console.log()` the array and see the newly updated values.  However, `ngFor` still does not seem to be iterating through the updated array and modifying the DOM accordingly.

I'm also able to define the array with items in my code, and `ngFor` will correctly iterate and display the values.

It was to my understanding that the DOM should be updated according to the state that is presented within the component, but I am probably missing something.

Here's my code.

**TypeScript**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
  selector: "app-data-item",
  templateUrl: "./data-item.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./data-item.component.css"]
})
export class DataItemComponent implements OnInit {
  public dataArray: Array<object> = [];

  //Using ngFor to iterate through this array would work w/ no problem.
  anotherArray: Array<String> = ["Hello", "there"];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
  //A call is made to sendRequest from an outside component, which is able to successfully trigger this function
  sendRequest(requestBody: object) {
    this.http
      .post("http://localhost:4343/getProgramDetails", requestBody, {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
      })
      .subscribe(response => {
        const dataItems = response[0]["key"];

        dataItems.forEach(item => {
          //Push an itemInstance to the dataArray variable
          const itemInstance = {
            description: item["description"],
            type: incentive["type"],
            value: incentive["value"]
          };
          this.dataArray.push(itemInstance);
        });
        //Am able to see array values here
        console.log(this.dataArray);
      });
  }
}
```

**Angular Template**

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Vehicle</td>
        <td>Incentive Type</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
    </tr>
    <ul>
        <!-- Items won't print here when array is updated -->
        <li *ngFor="let item of dataArray">
            {{ item }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @LLai Nope, no errors.

Comment: hmm, can you create a plnkr that recreates the issue. Here is a simpler plnkr demonstrating this concept working (https://plnkr.co/edit/VSARynj1Y05hPBcecrGB?p=preview). is the template you posted from DataItemComponent? Or is it a child component

Comment: try this `this.dataArray = [...this.dataArray , itemInstance];` instead of `.push`

Answer (score 2):

```js
this.dataArray = this.http
  .post("http://localhost:4343/getProgramDetails", requestBody, {
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
  })
  .map(response => {
    let result = [];
    const dataItems = response[0]["key"];
    dataItems.forEach(item => {
      //Push an itemInstance to the dataArray variable
      const itemInstance = {
        description: item["description"],
        type: incentive["type"],
        value: incentive["value"]
      };
      result.push(itemInstance);
    });
    return result;
  });
```

and in your view

```html
<li *ngFor="let item of (dataArray | async)">
  {{ item }}
</li>
```