# ngFor not updating DOM when array is updated Angular2

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, dom, ngfor

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47189631/angular-ngfor-not-updating-dom-when-array-is-updated) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979831/angular-2-with-ngfor-is-it-possible-to-update-values-without-rebuilding-the-d), but I couldn't make it work.

I have this:

**HTML:**

```
<span *ngFor="let block of blocks; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
   {{block.description}}:
</span>
```

**Component:**

```
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
styleUrls: [ 'component.css' ],
templateUrl: 'component.html'})

export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
blocks: any = [];

constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadCourse();
    }

    private loadCourse(){ 
  this.http.get(url + parseInt(localStorage.getItem('id'))).map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .subscribe(resp => {
        this.blocks = resp.blocks;
      });

    }

    trackByFn(index, item) {
      return index;
    }
```

An then, after some user interaction, I trigger this two lines:

```
 localStorage.setItem('id','4');
 this.loadCourse();
```

And the blocks array is updated, but the DOM is not updated, so I don't see the new descriptions in the HTML.

What's missing?

Thanks!!

Comment: have you tried printing `resp.blocks` if it has a value?

Comment: Yes! It has new values.